What to do with 'simple' questions?
over the last years I have made the observation that we have a lot of questions in this board that may be deemed 'simple' from and are commmonly answered using the comment-function instead of the answer-functionality. I myself am not exempt from that behavior. This is a recent example.
Going forward, I'd suggest that it might helpful for OPs to offer a full answer, and we may then close duplicates more easily.
My question has been asked on this meta a couple of times iirc, so it seems that there's no consensus, yet.
What do you people think?

If credit is given, I don't mind people copying the comments to an answer. Depending on the comment, feel free to rephrase to make it a better answer.

I think these stack exchanges are very good. I have learned a lot from them. I think there some very smart and well educated people that post on the stack exchanges. However, at times I find the people that post on the stack exchanges have big egos and nasty personalities. I am not the only one who feels this way.
Therefore, my view is that if somebody posts a simple (and well written question that shows effort) that we allow it and if feasible, provide a good answer. Over time, that person should learn more and he/she will feel good about this site.
